# VirtualBox Ubuntu32 v14.04 sudo command not found

Tags: mount, sudo, virtualbox

This is a weird problem, "sudo su" can run but "sudo mount..." cannot run.

My environment is VirtualBox Ubuntu 32-bit 14.04 installed in Windows 10, and I want to share a folder between Ubuntu and Windows so that files can easily copy from each other.

Following command if run successfully, the folder can share properly. And it does successfully sometimes (unfortunately I cannot remember how), but most of the time after startup VB Ubuntu, and open a terminal to run the command, get following:

```
pis@pis-VirtualBox:~$ ﻿sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedVM Downloads
No command '﻿sudo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
sudo: command not found

pis@pis-VirtualBox:~$ type -p sudo
/usr/bin/sudo

pis@pis-VirtualBox:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for pis: 

root@pis-VirtualBox:/home/pis# ﻿sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedVM Downloads
No command '﻿sudo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
sudo: command not found

root@pis-VirtualBox:/home/pis# apt-get install sudo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sudo is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.

root@pis-VirtualBox:/home/pis# ﻿sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedVM Downloads
No command '﻿sudo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
sudo: command not found

root@pis-VirtualBox:/home/pis# echo ${PATH}
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

root@pis-VirtualBox:/home/pis# ﻿sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedVM Downloads
No command '﻿sudo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
sudo: command not found

root@pis-VirtualBox:/home/pis# type -p sudo
/usr/bin/sudo

root@pis-VirtualBox:/home/pis# /usr/bin/﻿sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedVM Downloads  
bash: /usr/bin/﻿sudo: No such file or directory
```

Anyone can advise how to solve it? Or need more information?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: after "sudo su", just run the command without "sudo"